# Animate reused svg independently

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want some SVGs to animate on click. The SVG is defined once and has been reused multiple times with the `<use>` tag.
I wrote the following code:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #0af;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
    <symbol id="tick" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <polyline points="15,50 40,75 85,25" style="stroke-width:10; fill:none; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round;" stroke-dasharray="120">
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="120" to="0" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" begin="click" />
        </polyline>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg><use href="#tick"/></svg>
<svg><use href="#tick"/></svg>
<svg><use href="#tick"/></svg>
<svg><use href="#tick"/></svg>
```

The problem is, if I click on a single SVG, all the instances of that SVG are getting animated, which is not what I want. I want them to animate independently. What is the best way to do this other than embedding the complete SVG multiple times?

Comment: What's wrong with embedding the complete SVG multiple times, especially given that is the way to do this?

Comment: Working fine in Firefox, probably some Chrome bug.
You can try to use some svg animation library if you dont want to copy svg's.

Comment: You are right @Winns. I have tried this in all the major browsers, out of them only Firefox plays the animation independently. According to me, Firefox implements it differently than the standards.

Comment: @winns no, Firefox is broken.

Comment: [SVG2 UseEventHandling](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseEventHandling): Any event listeners defined on an element in the referenced graphics must also listen for the same event, at the same capture phase, on each instance of that element in a use-element shadow tree. ..... The user agent must ensure that the list of event listeners for each element instance is synchronized to match its corresponding element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your `svg` in a file and access it in document tree like this:

```
<object data="tick.svg"></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is duplicate ids

create a Web Component (supported in all modern Browsers) that injects your **once defined** SVG

```
<svg-tick id=ONE stroke="red"></svg-tick>
<svg-tick id=TWO></svg-tick>
<svg-tick id=THREE></svg-tick>
<svg-tick id=FOUR stroke="blue"></svg-tick>
```

[image]

You can add more Web Component goodies, like attributes and a single clickhandler...

I changed the polyline to `path`, makes it easier with a `pathLength=100`, no need for calculations

`id` not required, you can also generate a unique value with `"ID"+new Date()/1`

```html
<style>
  svg {
    border: 1px solid #0af;
    stroke: green;
    width: 120px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  #TWO svg { stroke: goldenrod;   }
</style>

<svg-tick id=ONE stroke="red"></svg-tick>
<svg-tick id=TWO></svg-tick>
<svg-tick id=THREE></svg-tick>
<svg-tick id=FOUR stroke="blue"></svg-tick>
<script>
  customElements.define('svg-tick', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let id = this.id;
      let stroke = this.hasAttribute("stroke") 
                        ? ` stroke=${this.getAttribute("stroke")} ` 
                        : "";
      this.innerHTML = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path id="${id}" d="M15,50 40,75 85,25" pathLength="100" 
        stroke-width="10" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
        stroke-dasharray="100" ${stroke}/>
    <animate id="${id}" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="100" to="0" 
           dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" begin="click" />
</svg>`;
      this.onclick = (evt) => console.log('clicked',id);
    }
  });
</script>
```

svga

Comment: Thanks a lot! The Custom web component method is a great way for this thing. No hacking around and also more cross-browser. For your information, you do not necessarily require unique IDs. You can add everything under a shadow tree inside the custom component and there will be no conflicts.

Comment: True, shadowDOM excapsulates, but the global CSS will no longer be applied, unless you go for CSS properties, ::parts etc.